# How can I find work Items assigned by me to specific list of users (Developers) in Microsoft Visual Studio TFS?

Tags: tfs

How to get all Work Item Type is equal to Bug which is Assigned by me to the team members with specific date range?

Also, Vise Versa, If team members assigned the bug themselves from my bucket list with a specific date range.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Did you try to create a query?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Yes I have tried Changed By(Field) - Was Ever (Operator) - @Me(Value) with Assigned To - Was Ever - User (With group clauses). Now I am trying to get the date when I assigned Work Item to the user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best you can do is to setup a query with the following options:

```
    Work Item Type =  Bug
And Assigned To    =  @Me
And Changed By     <> @Me
And Changed Date   >  @Today - 7
```

This would show every bug assigned to you that was last changed by someone else within the last last 7.

By swapping the Assigned To and Changed By parameters you can turn this around.

You can also use a group name in the Assigned To or Changed By criteria to limit the query.